# Angular 5 - read config file in internal folder

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

Im following this way to do this:

Using HttpClient and this code: this.http.get("url/assets/file.json");

But, if my config file is in the assets folder, my info is opened to web.

How can I read this file on internal folder (not in assets)?

Comment: Every single file you publish with your angular app is public. What do you mean by "read this file on internal folder"?

Comment: I have routes to my components, then, when I try access another file (out of assets folder), my code redirect to 404 page. If I need read files, this need stay on assets or another folder if I have reference on '.angular-cli.json' following this struct:

 "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "FOLDERNAMEHERE",
        "favicon.ico"
      ], 
...
}

Do you know how can I read my config file, but in "internal folder". My config file don't can access in url for example.

Comment: you have to consider that if you use http.get('url/assets/file.json'), url/assets/file.json should be accessible from anywhere. So why putting in a typescript config/constant is a better way if you do not want it

Comment: Thanks @Fetrarij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put your config file like how environment.ts did? your config file will be compiled like other ts files.

you just create a typescript file and add your config in a variable:

```
export const myconfig = 'your config here';
```

and you don't need to call an http for it, just;

```
import { myconfig } from 'your_config_file'
```

Comment: Yes, but, I need compile everything again. This is the better way for this problem? Or have another way to do this?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: if you want to use json file and http call, it should always accessible from anywhere. So I think this one is the better way.